# Data File Size Stays Same Whereas Log File Size Is Increasing

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following snippet to track the data and log file size increase after certain operations:

```
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space (database_id, data_used_size, log_used_size)
    SELECT
          DB_ID()
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN space_used END)
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN space_used END)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.[type], space_used = SUM(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8)
        FROM sys.database_files s
        GROUP BY s.[type]
    ) t;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

The problem is, after each write operation, log file size increases as expected but the data file size stays the same for 4 or five operations and then suddenly increases.

Why would this be?

Comment: Sounds like maybe the DB is just buffering operations and only flushes to the disk after it accumulates so many

Comment: @KarlO I tried to use CHECKPOINT to force flush but didn't help.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with databases so my insights are limited. What size of updates are these that you're pushing? If they're too small the file system might have larger blocks, so the file may read as the same size while the data within is growing little by little.

Comment: What are your autogrowth settings on the data file?

Comment: @KarlO When the change occurs after several trails of the same operation, I divide the total change in data file size by the number of trials and it is about 7kb-16kb of change per trial.

Comment: @JacobH It is as default, I did not touch the autogrowth settings.

Comment: I would look at your autogrowth settings, as @JacobH suggested. Seems like that might be what's happening based on a cursory google search. Basically, sounds like the db file only expands when it runs out of room, and then it expands in a configured manner beyond the space actually required, which sounds exactly like what you're experiencing. There might be some way you can watch for those autogrowth events too to see if they correspond to when you see the file size increase.